# maven "churchofjesuschrist.org" issue

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

1. I have created a dummy java project with IntelliJ using the maven template
2. Edited my pom.xml and added the following:

   ```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
     <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
     <version>12.2.0.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. The library comes with errors, if I cat the downloaded file at my local repo, this is what I see:

   ```
   $ cat .m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc6/12.2.0.1/ojdbc6-12.2.0.1.jar

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Out of Service</title>
   <style>
   ... some style ...
   </style>
   </head>
   <body id="error-page">

   <div class="supercenter">
           <h1>This website is down for maintenance.</h1>
           <p>We apologize for the inconvenience. Please come back later.</p>
           <p><a href="javascript:history.back()">Go Back</a>.</p>

           <p>Please check the URL for proper spelling and capitalization.
           If you're having trouble locating a page on churchofjesuschrist.org, try visiting
           <a href="https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/">churchofjesuschrist.org</a>
           or enter a search term in the field below.</p>
           <div id="search">
                   <form accept-charset="utf-8" method="get" action="https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/search">
                           <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="eng">
                           <span class="search-field"><input type="text" name="query" maxlength="150" class="ac_input"></span>
                           <input type="submit" value="⌕" class="search-button">
                   </form>
           </div>

           <br>
           <p><a href="https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/tools/feedback?lang=eng&amp;body=Error%3ahttps%3a//www.churchofjesuschrist.org/lb">Leave Feedback</a></p>
           <div class="pf-logo">
                   <a href="https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/" class="ldschurch-logotype">
                           <span class="ldschurch-logotype__text">The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints</span>
                   </a>
           </div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Is there some kind of issue/outage with maven central repository ? any ideas? 
It is happening with other libs too, I just show one to keep it simple, but this is an old project with many other dependencies, the previous example just show the issue in a simple way so everyone can replicate it

When I run mvn I see this:

```
Downloading from codelds: https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo/com/oracle/ojdbc6/12.2.0.1/ojdbc6-12.2.0.1.pom
```

That URL is the one beign downloaded on all dependency files

Comment: Sounds like Maven settings or DNS problems. Check `.m2/settings.xml` and do an `nslookup` on the hosts referenced therein to make sure they're pointing where they should.

Comment: that artifactId does not exist in the maven central repo. [`com.oracle`](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle/) shows `ojdbc` and `ojdbc14`, not your `ojdbc6`. That is not related to your error page though.

Comment: @f1sh it exist https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc6/12.2.0.1

Comment: @DavidConrad I don't have a .m2/settings.xml

Comment: The code.lds.org repo is run by the Church of Latter Day Saints, and it is currently down for maintenance. If you don't have a .m2/settings.xml in your home directory, that repo could also be hardcoded in your pom.xml, so check that too.

Comment: I don't have it in the pom either, it should be a default somewhere outside my dummy project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first of all, mvnrepository.com is not MavenCentral and has nothing to do with it.

MavenCentral does not contain `ojdbc6.jar` and I don't know whether other sources for it are legal.

That strange repository that is now "down for maintenance" must be somewhere in your `settings.xml`, your POM or one of your parent POMs or maybe even dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for this comment (and thanks @f1sh too) I was thinking that mvnrepository.com (or any other) was just a search engine for maven central, I'm going to review the project deeply to find that reference, I will let you know if this solves the issue. Thanks

Comment: I had that repo added manually, I removed it, created a local repo with the private jars and done, Thanks again for your comment